# How do I make a list with a custom layout that has dynamic size and dynamic position?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-fragments, android-scrollview

[image]

Here is my aim:

- The first image must have different height from the others.
- The second and third images must be in the same row.
- Odd rows have one image.
- Even rows has two images.
- The image must be in a text View with dynamic text and transparent.
- The list will be in part of layout not all it.
- The list must scroll.

Comment: Is this really a list? Or is it some images positioned in a particular layout?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: not list i think i want to make image view and text view in a fragment

Comment: and this fragment take the bitmap ant string of text and height and width and it position and add it in layout

Comment: or two fragment one has one image and the second has two ?

Answer (score 1):

This library can perhaps help you achieve that kind of UI.
https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid

`An Android staggered grid view which supports multiple columns with rows of varying sizes.`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with some layout nesting. It sounds like each "row" in your list contains two rows itself.